# Issue Related to SelectMany function in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables in Database:

1. PostCalculationLine
2. PostCaluclationLineProduct

PostCalculationLineProduct(table2) contains Foriegn key of PostCalucationLineId(table1)

In C# code I have two different Models for these two tables as follows:

```
public class PostCalculationLine : BaseModel
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    //some other properties go here
    public virtual IList<PostCalculationLineProduct> PostCalculationLineProducts { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public class PostCalculationLineProduct : BaseModel
 {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //some other properties go here
}
```

Now in Entityframework code, I fetch data from `PostCalculationLineProduct` as follows:

```
PostCalculationLineRepository pclr = new PostCalculationLineRepository();
DataSourceResult dsrResult = pclr.Get()
    .SelectMany(p => p.PostCalculationLineProducts)
    .Where(c => c.Product.ProductType.Id == 1 && c.DeletedOn == null)
    .Select(c => new HourGridViewModel()
         {
            Id = c.Id,
            Date = c.From,
            EmployeeName = c.Employee != null ?c.Employee.Name:string.Empty,
            Description= c.Description,
            ProductName = c.Product != null?c.Product.Name :string.Empty,
            From = c.From,
            To = c.Till,
            Quantity = c.Amount,
            LinkedTo = "OrderName",
            Customer ="Customer"
            PostCalculationLineId = ____________
        })
    .ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

In the above query I want to get PostCalculationLineId(from Table1) marked with underLine. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: How are the foreign keys setup? Do you not have a reference to the parent record in `PostCalculationLineProduct`?

Comment: In C# Code i do not have reference of PostCalculationLine in PostCalculationLineProduct..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) of SelectMany to achieve this:-

```
  DataSourceResult dsrResult = pclr.Get()
                .SelectMany(p => p.PostCalculationLineProducts,
                (PostCalculationLineProductObj,PostCalculationLineObj) => 
                         new { PostCalculationLineProductObj,PostCalculationLineObj })
                .Where(c => c.PostCalculationLineProductObj.Product.ProductType.Id == 1 
                       && c.PostCalculationLineProductObj.DeletedOn == null)
                .Select(c => new HourGridViewModel()
                {
                    Id = c.PostCalculationLineProductObj.Id,
                    Date = c.PostCalculationLineProductObj.From,
                    //Other Columns here
                    PostCalculationLineId = c.PostCalculationLineObj.Id
                };
```

This will flatten the `PostCalculationLineProducts` list and returns the flattened list combined with each `PostCalculationLine` element.